# Inserting Multiple Rows of Data after every row

Tags: excel, insert, rows

I have a spreadsheet of about 1,000 rows of data.

I am attempting to edit the spreadsheet to insert/paste the same two rows of data after every row.

All I seem to find is how to insert blank rows.

I have two rows of the exact same data to insert after each existing row.

Is this possible and if so, how?

Comment: how many columns in each row? are you able to share some pictures of what the 1000 rows look like, and what the 2 rows (to be inserted) look like, and how you want to stack them (say using 10 rows as an example)? I think it can be done either manually, via `#powerquery` or via `#vba`

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stacked.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel (no VBA needed):

[image]

1. Create a helper column, numbered from 1 to the end of the data.

[image]

2. Copy the helper column and paste it at the end of the current helper column, so you have the same set of numbers twice.

[image]

3. Fill in the rest of the data with the second rows you want.

[image]

4. Repeat the helper column again (just one set), so now you have the same set of numbers three times.

[image]

5. Fill in these with the third rows you want.

[image]

6. Sort smallest to largest on the helper column.

[image]

7. Delete the helper column.

[image]

Now you should have the same data you started with, but with the new rows inserted after every row you previously had.